# tfpdf cell with php variable containing integer throws Trying to access array offset on value of type int in tfpdf.php,

Tags: php

I created a pdf with tfpdf and want to show a variable holding a result of a calculation like $result=4+5. when I put this variable $result in a cell like

```
$pdf->Cell(15,5,$result,'','','',false);
```

It throws  "NOTICE: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in tfpdf.php on line 2273"
this is the line

```
$h = ord($str[$i]);
```

In the UTF8StringToArray($str) function, the function is obviously awaiting a string, actually, tfpdf is awaiting the third param to be a string. But I never realized it throws this NOTICE when I put a php variable in a cell containing an integer value. I guess I have to put the variable in "" like "result" or convert to a string like `strval($result)`.

How do I do it correctly?

When I put the variable in "" like "result" and converted to string like `strval($result)` and the Notice was wrong. But I've never seen the Notice before and wondering if this is normal.

Comment: If `$h = ord($str[$i]);` is really line 2273 of the notice, then I would think that `$str` is an integer?

Comment: Any PHP version from 7.4 onwards should have given you a notice or warning, https://3v4l.org/WSHNu But it is of course possible that you had _displaying_ those suppressed via the PHP error_reporting level before or in a different environment.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, no this is the text (string) for the pdf to be generated, ord is converting string to int 0-255, tfpdf is calculating the width of string there or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf->Cell(15,5,(string)$result,'','','',false);
//or
$pdf->Cell(15,5,strval($result),'','','',false);
```

Both of these will convert $result to a string before passing it to the Cell() function, avoiding the notice. This is a good practice to ensure you're passing the expected data types to functions.

Comment: yes, thats what i tried and the Notice was gone, but i wanted to clarify, that this is normal behavior, and  i should NOT pass fpdf as third parameter (which should be the text to display) a php-variable containing an integer value. it needs to be converted like mentioned? i thought i can pass there a variable no matter if string or integer.